# Gradle - Android - In App Review causes compile error - Amplify old dependency

Tags: android, gradle, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I am trying to integrate In App Review and I get this compile error:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.testing.FakeReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Edit: I ran the command: `./gradlew app:dependencies >> deps.txt`
and found out that the conflict is caused by Amplify core. It has a dependency on `androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.4` for some reason and that's has `com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1` inside.

How can I prevent Amplify causing this? How to solve this confilct?

[Here is the dependency tree](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ov3wKdVkE1P2vqsSi6wIO3YAKkTOtlAh/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Sometimes this type of error appear when you don't have depencencies up to date. Try update your depencies to the last version. Also I recommand you if you are using android Studio to "Ctrl alt F" and then type the class name to see what dependencies causes these errors.

Comment: @LoïcJackotin already done. it is all up to date

Comment: Can you add all your dependencies?

Comment: @LoïcJackotin I added a link with dependency tree

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing the gradle file:

```
 // gradle imports from Amplify docs below.
implementation('com.amplifyframework:aws-storage-s3:1.35.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
}

implementation('com.amplifyframework:aws-auth-cognito:1.35.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
}
// Amplify core dependency
implementation('com.amplifyframework:core:1.35.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'
}
```

Comment: not same for me, but it gave me hint of what I have to exclude. Thanks!

Comment: what if I get `Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules core-1.8.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.8.0) and core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)`  but the only lib I added is `'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'` which can contain the core

Comment: so I have no Idea to which dep I should add `exclude group: 'com.google.android.play', module: 'core'`